# RedirectToaction and method calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is the default index function of my home controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return NewPosts();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

and this is the newposts function in the same home controller file

```
public ActionResult NewPosts()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have log onto my account and I close my browser. Then I reopen it visiting the same index page, I see my identity (Welcome myusername) but the newposts function is not called and thus it doesnot display the newposts view as expected.

Why is that ? How can I fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way of getting this to work would be setting up a default page as 'NewPosts' for the site via the web.config. Then in your web.config, you can set the failed login page as 'Index'. This will cause users once they are log in to be sent to the 'NewPosts' page. If they close the browser (and their authentication cookie has not expired) then they will be sent to the 'NewPosts' page as well. If they are not logged in, then they will be kicked to the 'Index' page. Your if statement in your Index action method would no longer be required, as the web config forms authentication takes care of this for you in a more robust way. Here is an example of what the web config could look like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Home/NewPosts" > 
      </forms> 
</authentication>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) for more web.config info concerning forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about the controller, it's about caching of your browser.

If you hit Ctrl+F5 on the first page, it should recognize you as unauthorized.

I know this is not a real solution to force website visitors to hit Ctrl+F5 to refresh their browsers. There are many article in internet to tackle this kind of caching behavior, serach for them.

Two important points about your code:

1- Change `return NewPosts();` to:

```
 RedirectToAction("NewPost");
```

2- Decoreacte NewPosts method with [Authorize] attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult NewPosts()
{
    return View();
}
```